# How to bind object from the header to object class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have my webpage sending an object in the get request. The object contains 2 string and 3 boolean values. The reason I use an object to be passed from the webpage is because I am not able to pass boolean values in the header.

I need this incoming object to be mapped to class variables.

The code I am using is below.

**Sending object:**

```
return this.http.get(this.statusReportUrl, {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            headers:  <any>myObject
```

**Receiving object:**

```
@RequestMapping("/Logs")
public void createLog(HttpServletResponse response, LogRO logRO)  throws IOException {
        }
```

I expect myObject to be mapped to logRO. However this is not happening, and logRO has null values.

**I have also tried:**

```
@RequestMapping("/Logs")
public void createLog(HttpServletResponse response,
                      @RequestParam(value ="myObject" LogRO logRO)  
                      throws IOException {
        }
```

This didn't work either.

How can I map the myObject to LogRO?

Answer (score 0):

try use `@RequestHeader Object object`